# botao + link ajuda ae

Tags: html

to fazendo um site para um trabalho no curso, preciso criar um login ou cadastro tanto faz mas quando eu coloco um botão (button/header/input) estou usando "required" e os botão passam direto n pede para preencher (Obs: estao comentado pq tava testando )

[image: Imagem Do Codigo]

Comment: **1)** [Não coloque seu código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132), o site tem suporte a código fonte, basta fazer o [tour], ler o guia de [ask] e acessar a [help]; **2)** Sempre utilize títulos informativos na pergunta; o título "botão + link ajuda ae" não deixa claro sobre o que está perguntado; **3)** Sempre que perguntar elabore um [mcve] demonstrando o problema para que possamos reproduzí-lo; postar um trecho de código que supostamente está com erro mas comentá-lo não faz sentido.

Comment: Sobre o problema em si, não faz sentido você ter um `<a>` dentro de um `<button>`; o primeiro serve para navegação, o segundo para executar uma ação. Como você pressionou o primeiro, você estará **navegando** entre páginas, não submetendo um formulário, por isso o *required* não é considerado.

Comment: @LeonardoNegrão, reverti a sua edição por descaracterizar a pergunta original.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, eu realmente fiquei com um pouco de dúvidas, pois minha edição trouxa a resposta rs

Comment: @LeonardoNegrão "Descaracteriza" basicamente porque o problema citado na pergunta está justamente nas partes comentadas do código, então não faz sentido removê-las.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, entendi, obrigado pela explicação

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fiz a edição de seu código (pergunte sempre com trechos relevantes do código de forma escrita) e só por reescrever seu código já funcionou:

```html
<div class="section">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="get" action="">
    <input type="email" class="Login" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required><br />
    <input type="password" class="Login" name="Senha" placeholder="Senha" required><br />
    <input type="submit" class="button"">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Fique atento em utilizar um código limpo e padronizado, por exemplo, o campo Email no atributo name em seu exemplo está maiúsculo e "senha" no próximo campo está minúsculo.

Boa sorte